# I loaded my LWJGL game engine onto a Windows 11 computer, and the collisions of polygons started getting really jagged

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have been coding in LWJGL 2 for a while, mostly in Windows 10.  Intersecting polygons looked fine on any Windows 10 computer I loaded the engine on.  Then when uploading the program to Intellij on a Windows 11 computer, the program broke.  When really close to the intersecting polygons, everything looks fine:[image: Polygon intersections in close proximity]

But when at a distance, the jagged edges begin appearing:
[image: Polygon intersections at a distance]

I have tried loading it on any other computer, and it works just fine (as long as it's pre-windows 11).  I've made sure that all the code is identical.  I've tested different JDK versions, Intellij versions, and Java versions, and they all don't seem to have any bearing on this issue in particular.  The only real thing in the code in relation to both distance and detail was mipmapping, but removing it does not affect the issue in any way either.  Any assistance would be appreciated.